# How does Ziteboard work?

Tags: websocket, html5-canvas, webrtc

Ziteboard is a shareable board based on the HTML5 Canvas - [www.ziteboard.com](http://www.ziteboard.com).

I don't see too much in the Network tab in Chrome Dev Tools.

Does it use websockets for sharing the board, WebRTC, or maybe anything else? How does communication work, undo function?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It uses websockets. See the attached image.
You have to have the network tab open when the page loads to be able to see the websocket frames and connections.

[image: websocket]

Comment: I dont' see anything there when I draw! Websocket is not listed in the network tab connections list

Comment: Did you share the board? You have to share it to get a websocket. Without sharing it is just a local canvas. Also... do not forget to open the network tab before loading the page.